# SQL: What are phone number formatting options?

Tags: sql

SQL: What are phone number formatting options?

I query my  SQL Database for a phone number:

816-123-4567

I want to output it is as:

816 123-4567.

What steps do I take to achieve this result in an SQL environment?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and string functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard SQL solution would be:

```
select substring(phone, 1, 3) || ' ' || substring(phone, 5, 8)
```

There may be simpler solutions in other databases.  For instance, in SQL Server:

```
select stuff(phone, 4, 1, ' ')
```

And in MySQL:

```
select insert(phone, 4, 1, ' ')
```

Note:  These are specific the the format you have provided in your question.  If you have other formats, then you might need more complicated logic.

Comment: Thank you all! This totally worked! I'm now on to trying to figure out how to get my next part set.

Comment: @HaywoodJackson . . . If this answers your question, you should consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX functions.

SUBSTRING gets a part of the string according to given indexes.

CHARINDEX gets the index of the character that triggers your String separation.

Below is an MSSQL Server query.
According to your DBMS, the function names can vary, but the logic will is the same.

Query :

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING('816-123-4567', 0, CHARINDEX('-', '816-123-4567') ) + 

' ' +

SUBSTRING('816-123-4567', CHARINDEX('-', '816-123-4567') + 1 , LEN('816-123-4567') - 
CHARINDEX('-', '816-123-4567') )
```

And the result :

```
816 123-4567
```

When we put your field and table name instead of static values :

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(YourPhoneField, 0, CHARINDEX('-', YourPhoneField) ) + 

' ' +

SUBSTRING(YourPhoneField, CHARINDEX('-', YourPhoneField) + 1 , LEN(YourPhoneField) - 
CHARINDEX('-', YourPhoneField) )

FROM YourTableName
```

Comment: I'm surprised this answer is upvoted.  It is specific to one database -- and the question has no database tag.  And in SQL Server, this is a much simpler solution.

Comment: I'm using the DBeaver application. I apologize, not sure on the specific SQL database being used. I'll make sure to try all this morning. It's really just placing all this info in that 1 select field for my understanding.